# 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration' is obsolete: 'this API is deprecated.'

Tags: azure, deployment

I had to reinstall a version of `Visual Studio 2013 Update 4` on my machine.

I had v2.3 of the Azure toolset working with my cloud service just fine.

When I loaded the project again into Visual Studio, it asked me if I wanted to upgrade to v2.5 or download v2.3. I tried to download v2.3, but the link wouldn't work.

I then upgraded to v2.5 which blew my cloud service to bits when it tried to publish it.

I'm getting the following attached errors:

The first dialog is basically is asking me to upgrade to 2.5 or download 2.3.

The images are returning the three errors when the service tries to get published:

```
1.Starting role... Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException
2.Role has encountered an error and has stopped. Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException
3.'microsoft.windows.azure.diagnostics.directoryconfiguration' is obsolete: 'this api is deprecated.'
```

It worked fine with v2.3 and now with 2.5, it's getting the above errors.

Can someone please inform me how I can correct this issue so my cloud service will be published correctly?

Comment: There have been some breaking changes in SDK 2.5 for diagnostics. Please make sure that you read them here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx. My recommendation would be not to upgrade your solution to SDK 2.5. If I'm not mistaken, you could very well have SDK 2.5 installed on your computer but having your project making use of older version. HTH.

Comment: I do have sdk 2.5 installed on my on my computer, because it wouldn't let me download sdk 2.3. How can I get the 2.3 installed again? The webinstaller only lists v2.5 for VS 2012, 13, & 15.

Comment: Try this link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

Comment: I can't.. when I try, it says "a later version of Microsoft asp.net & web tools 2013.1 - visual studio 2013 is already installed.

Comment: If I try and delete my existing cloud service and try and add a new one with 2.5, should that work correctly then?